# Syncing sprite animation and physics in Godot

Tags: animation, 2d, physics, godot

In a 2D scene in Godot, I have a factory belt transporting items. The items are physics objects (with linear damping = 1 so they do not accelerate too much), the belts have an Area2D with a gravity force that transports the items. The belts have a sprite animation showing the belt moving.
I can sync the sprite animation reasonably well to the speed the items reach on the belts by adjusting the AnimatedSprite's speed scale. Any divergence looks odd visually of course, as the items will either be moving faster or slower than the belt.

I am worried that differences in FPS across devices may cause the visual correctness to break. 
Should I just stop worrying? Is there a better way to implement belts moving items? I am aware that I can implement the item movement myself instead of relying on the physics engine - but this won't solve the problem of syncing with the belt animation.

Comment: AnimationPlayer has physics playback process mode and speed scale. Maybe that would be better than an AnimatedSprite?

Comment: Thank you @hola, I'll look into that.